# Let $A$ and $B$ be sets. If $A$ is infinite and $A\subset B$, the $B$ is infinite.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Proof by Contradiction: Suppose $A$ is infinite, $A\subset B$, and $B$ is infinite.

Since $A\subset B$, then $|A|\leq |B|$.

Since A is infinite and $|A|\leq |B|$, then $B$ must be infinite. But $B$ is finite. Contradiction occurs.

Therefore $B$ is infinite.

Is this enough to verify the statement.

Comment: I suspect you mean to say 'and $B$ is finite.' In the first sentence of your post? In that case, the proof is good.

Answer (score 2):

The argument you provided is essentially a tautological restatement of the thing you are asked to prove in the "$\lvert A\rvert\le\lvert B\rvert$" formalism, so I doubt the person who gave you the assignment deems it a valid proof. For instance, you are not using explicitly the fact that "infinite set" has an actual meaning, other than satisfying some (true, but largely unspecified) formal property.

I'd rather go with: let $S\subsetneq A$ such that there is a bijective function $f:A\to S$. Then, $S\cup(B\setminus A)\subsetneq B$ and the function \begin{align}\overline f:B&\to S\cup(B\setminus A)\\ \overline f(x)&=\begin{cases}f(x)&\text{if }x\in A\\ x&\text{if }x\in B\setminus A\end{cases} \end{align}
is bijective.

Comment: I gotcha. Thank you for the input. Not an assignment, just trying to learn this stuff.

Comment: Maybe it is good to clarify that this it proving that "if A is not Dedekind-finite and $A\subset B$ then $B$ is not Dedekind finite".

Comment: @MlazhinkaShungGronzalezLeWy Yes, I assumed this definition of infinite set (or, rather, that the different definitions could all be deemed equivalent).

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you want contradiction, assume $f:B\to n$ is bijective for some natural number $n$.

Then $f|_A:A\to f(A)$ is bijective. And since $f(A)\subset n$, then $f(A)$ is itself a natural number.

This contradicts that $A$ is infinite since it shows a bijection from $A$ to a natural number.